# jQuery Animate Width: 'Toggle' Behaving Unexpectedly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am making a sliding search bar using jQuery. I am using

```
$(".search a").unbind('click').click(function(e){ 

    var searchParent = $(this).parent('.search');

    searchParent.children().children(".search-title").animate({
        width: 'toggle'
    });

    ...

});
```

This works perfectly on my home page, but when I navigate to other pages, I start running into issues (the code is EXACTLY the same on both pages – I am using PHP to include the code on both pages).

On my home page, when I slide the element out for the first time, jQuery assigns a display property of "inline-block," which works exactly right. However, on pages other than the home page, it gets "block" for the display property.

Why would this be happening? How do I fix it???

**EDIT:**
Here is the HTML associated with jQuery above.

```
<li class="search">
    <a href="#">
       <span class="fa fa-search"></span>
       <span class="search-title">Search</span>
    </a>
    <input type="text" name="search" />
    <span class="fa fa-arrow-right"></span>
</li>
```

Comment: Please share the HTML part

Comment: Probably on those other pages you're running into CSS selector specificity issues, assigning that particular element some different styles - OR - `searchParent.children().children(".search-title")` is just wrong.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan I'm using a single external stylesheet and the code for the search bar is in a separate, single PHP file that is included on each subsequent page. So literally nothing is changing from page to page.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to implicitly declare the style using the `!important` on the css

```css
.search{
  
  display: inline-block !important;
  
  }
```

Hope this helped.